# Babel 7 this becomes _this angularjs

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm making an application using `ES6`, `AngularJS` and `babel-loader 7.1.4`, `Webpack 3` .
Everything worked fine until I created a service file:

This is my service:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (ngModule) => {

    ngModule.service('$ui', () => {


        //#region Methods

        /*
        * Trigger windows resize function.
        * */
        this.reloadWindowSize = () => {
            $(window).resize();
        };

        //#endregion
    });
};
```

After transpilling source code from ES6 to ES2015, my service became:

```
module.exports = function (ngModule) {

    ngModule.service('$ui', function () {

        //#region Methods

        /*
        * Trigger windows resize function.
        * */
        _this.reloadWindowSize = function () {
            $(window).resize();
        };

        //#endregion
    });
};
```

As you see, `this` now becomes `_this`, therefore, I cannot execute the function in service file.

This is my **babel configuration**

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: [['env', { "modules": false }]]
        }
    }
}
```

What wrong am I doing ?

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you,

Comment: I just want to know how to disable transpiling this to _this.

Comment: Your code is wrong. `this` is undefined in that context. Read about the differences between arrow functions and regular functions and you'll understand why.

Comment: BTW, ES6 and ES2015 are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch). I have found the answer.

I changed my service implementation from :

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (ngModule) => {

    ngModule.service('$ui', () => {


        //#region Methods

        /*
        * Trigger windows resize function.
        * */
        this.reloadWindowSize = () => {
            $(window).resize();
        };

        //#endregion
    });
};
```

To this:

```
module.exports = (ngModule) => {

    ngModule.service('$ui', () => {

        return {

            //#region Methods

            /*
            * Reload window size.
            * */
            reloadWindowSize: () => {
                $(window).resize();
            }

            //#endregion
        }
    });
};
```

Within service declaration, I return a set of functions and it worked.

Just want to let anyone know about this. It took me a night to find the answer.

Comment: `ngModule.service('$ui', () => {` - this is what `factory` is for. And you can't refer to service instances this way.

Comment: Can you explain more ? For now, I can inject the $ui service to my controller.

Comment: If you need to access service instance inside service method, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: As I understand correctly what you want to say that I can't inject another service instance into $ui service . If so, I already tried and it worked. Here is my repo : https://github.com/redplane/ng-structure.git (master branch)

Answer (score 3):

Arrow functions aren't just shortcuts for regular functions.

As [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) states,

> Two factors influenced the introduction of arrow functions: shorter functions and non-binding of this.

Since source code contains several nested arrow functions, `this` is retrieved from top-level scope through `_this` variable, which is `undefined`, because it's module scope, and strict mode is enabled.

It's semantically incorrect to use arrow functions for `service` services, because they are instantiated with `new` and use `this` as service instance, while arrows cannot be `new`ed and don't have own `this`.

It should be:

```
ngModule.service('$ui', function () {
    //#region Methods

    /*
    * Trigger windows resize function.
    * */
    this.reloadWindowSize = () => {
        $(window).resize();
    };

    //#endregion
});
```